# Need to display values retrived from web service asmx in android

Tags: android, web-services, asmx

I need to display retrived data from web service asmx in android.

```
private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    public boolean isOnline()
    {

        ConnectivityManager localConnectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService("connectivity");
        NetworkInfo localNetworkInfo = localConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (localNetworkInfo != null) && (localNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) && (localConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()) && (localConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");

        String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
        String URL = "http://example.com/example/GroupMessage/GroupMessage.asmx";

        String METHOD_NAME = "GroupList";

        String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GroupList";

        try {
            SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            Request.addProperty("PortalId","0");
            Request.addProperty("ModuleId", "1884");

            SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
            soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

            HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);               

            resultString = (SoapObject)soapEnvelope.getResponse();      

            Log.i(TAG, "Result Login: " + resultString);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");

        mInformationTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.informationTextView);

        mInformationTextView.setText(resultString.toString());

        /* Datas from web service */

        SoapObject request2 = (SoapObject)resultString.getProperty(0);

         for(int i=0; i<request2.getPropertyCount(); i++) {


             **///// code to display datas //////////**

         }

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Response" + resultString.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Now i am getting response like this ---
anyType{SalGM_GroupInfo=anyType{PortalId=0; ModuleId=1884; GroupId=1; GroupName=Test1; }; SalGM_GroupInfo=anyType{PortalId=0; ModuleId=1884; GroupId=2; GroupName=Test2; }; SalGM_GroupInfo=anyType{PortalId=0; ModuleId=1884; GroupId=3; GroupName=Test3; }; SalGM_GroupInfo=anyType{PortalId=0; ModuleId=1884; GroupId=4; GroupName=Test4; }; }

I need to display the output in android like below using **dynamic text view**

**PortalId=0 

ModuleId=1884 

GroupId=1

GroupName=Test1

PortalId=0 

ModuleId=1884

GroupId=2

GroupName=Test2

PortalId=0 

ModuleId=1884 

GroupId=3

GroupName=Test3

PortalId=0

ModuleId=1884

GroupId=4

GroupName=Test4**

Any suggestion please help ,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to display the data on activity after getting the response, If i'm right then you have to follow some steps otherwise ignore this answer & tell me in brief.

See this link http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-populate-listview-from-json.html

To achieve this you will have to create CustomAdapter class & use ListView for multiple data. Follow the above link how he has done the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert String response to JSONObject response and should parse into textviews.reffer the following link. http://andygeeks.blogspot.in/2014/04/parse-json-format-data-from-soap-web.html